# std queue pop a moved std string in multithreading

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, queue, thread-safety

I am currently implementing a string processor. I used to using single-thread, but it is kind of slow, so I would like to use multi-thread to boost it. Now it has some problems I could not solve on my own.

I use thread-safe queue to implement producer and consumer. And the `push` and `pop` method of the thread-safe queue is below, and if whole file is needed, take a look at [here](https://pastebin.com/Ekmd8PW4):

```cpp
template <typename Tp>
void ThreadSafeQueue<Tp>::enqueue(Tp &&data) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    q.emplace(std::forward<Tp>(data));
    cv.notify_one();
}

template <typename Tp>
bool ThreadSafeQueue<Tp>::dequeue(Tp &data) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    while (!broken && q.empty()) {
        cv.wait(lk);
    }
    if (!broken && !q.empty()) {
        data = std::move(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }
    return !broken;
}
```

When I use this struct to store string (aka `Tp`=`std::string`), problem occurs. I am using it this way:

producer:

```
__prepare_data__(raw_data)
std::vector<std::thread> vec_threads;
for(int i=0;i<thread_num;++i)
{
  vec_threads.emplace_back(consumer,std::ref(raw_data),std::ref(processed_data))
}
for(int i=0;i<thread_num;++i)
{
  if(vec_threads[i].joinable())
  {
    vec_thread[i].join();
  }
  __collect_data__(processed_data)
}
```

and consumer:

```
std::string buf;
while(deque(buf))
{
  __process__(buf)
}
```

In the above codes, all values passed to consumer threads are passed by reference (aks using `std::ref` wrapper), so the `__collect_data__` procedure is valid.

I will not meet any problem in these cases:

1. The number of string pieces is small. (This does not mean the string length is short.)
2. Only one consumer is working.

I will meet the problem in these cases:

1. The number of string is large, millions or so.
2. 2 or more consumers is working.

And what exception the system would throw varies between these two:

1. Corrupted double-linked list, followed by a bunch of memory indicator. GDB told me the line causing problem is the `pop` in the `dequeue` method.
2. Pure segment fault. GDB told me the problem occurred when consumer threads were joining.

The first case happens the most frequently, so I would like to ask as the title indicates, Would it cause any undefined behavior when `pop`ping an already moved `std::string`? Or if you have any other insights, please let me know!

Comment: `enqueue` and `dequeue` looks fine, but `dequeue` could be simplified: After the `wait` then `if(broken) return false; data = std::move(q.front()); q.pop(); return true;` - you don't need to check if `q.empty()` since it must have a value if `broken` is `false`

Comment: As for `pop`ing a moved-from `string` - that's perfectly fine too. I think we need to see a [mre].

Comment: `vec_threads.emplace_back(consumer,std::ref(raw_data),std::ref(processed_data))` looks to me like all the threads are working on the same data. You haven't shown how or where `enqueue` and `deque` are used, so its hard to be sure if this is related to your problem or not.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the bug but couldn't, it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

While there are issues with your code, there are none that explain your crash. I suggest you investigate your data processing code, not your queue.

For reference, your logic around queue shutdown is slightly wrong. For example, shutdown waits on the condition variable until the queue is empty but the dequeue operation does not notify on that variable. So you might deadlock.

It is easier to just ignore the "broken" flag in the dequeue operation until the queue is empty. That way the worker threads will drain the queue before quitting. Also, don't let the shutdown block until empty. If you want to wait until all threads are done with the queue, just join the threads.

Something like this:

```
template <typename Tp>
bool ThreadSafeQueue<Tp>::dequeue(Tp &data) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    while (!broken && q.empty()) {
        cv.wait(lk);
    }
    if (q.empty())
        return false; // broken
    data = std::move(q.front());
    q.pop();
    return true;
}
template <typename Tp>
void ThreadSafeQueue<Tp>::shutdown() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    broken = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

There are other minor issues, for example it is in practice more efficient (and safe) to unlock mutexes before notifying the condition variables so that the woken threads do not race with the waking thread on acquiring/releasing the mutex. But that is not a correctness issue.

I also suggest you delete the move constructor on the queue. You rightfully noted that it shouldn't be called. Better make sure that it really isn't.